# can't find /camera/camera_info and /camera/image_raw when using rostopic list command

Tags: ros, camera-calibration

i'm going to do the intrinsic calibration for my kinect camera, I've followed this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration
However, when I use command rostopic list, I just found 2 topics:

```
/rosout 
/rosout_agg
```

but didn't find wanted topics that are:

```
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
```

I've installed camera_calibration package, and I'm using ROS Indigo.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use a kinect and freenect driver for it, so the problem is I need to "roslaunch detection freenect.launch" first, then I can see my wanted topics that are /camera/rgb/image_color and camera:=/camera/rgb.

Comment: How is this a problem? If you want to see a topic in ros, then a node must be publishing that topic. Just launch the node in one terminal and habe it running all the time you need it..